# to get selected value in select tag

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div>
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="select"  onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">
<option value="english.php">English</option>
<option value="french.php">French</option>
<option value="spanish.php">Spanish</option>
</select>
</div>
```

i want to change language it work fine when i change the language but in dropdown it always shows english

Answer (score 2):

Add a `selected` attribute to the option you want to be selected when the page loads.

Comment: but selected attribute will select only that value.. but i want to display that value which i have selected like if a select english on page load it will select english and if i select spanish it will show spanish in dropdown..

Comment: @Nav — Put the selected attribute on the english option on english.php. Put the selected attribute on the spanish option on spanish.php. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another  tag that is blank.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/XYSXA/

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="select"  onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="english.php">English</option>
    <option value="french.php">French</option>
    <option value="spanish.php">Spanish</option>
</select>​
```

This way none of the options will be selected by default.

Alternatively, you may use the set the attribute `selected` inside one of the opening `<option>` tags to specify which language should be selected  by default. Example selecting French by default:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="select"  onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="english.php">English</option>
    <option value="french.php" selected>French</option>
    <option value="spanish.php">Spanish</option>
</select>​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XYSXA/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$file=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");
$file=ucwords($file);
?>
<option value="french.php" <?=($file=="French")?" selected='selected'":""?>>French</option>
```

I m assuming that you're using the pattern like French for french.php, Spanish For spanish.php,etc